# Correlation in general for LoadRunner

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

In general could anything coming from the server be correlated? All unique values being recorded could be correlated as long as it is created server side and passed in the server response?
Spesific for correlating values in the http headers returned from the server one would use "scope=headers" right?
What kind of other values could "scope" have? I know of body, but are there others?

It is not possible to correlate values generated client side by i.e. a JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlated values are returned from the server inside of the HTTP response stream.  If you need a value from Javascript then you have a couple of paths

- Convert your javascript function to the language of your virtual user (C, VB, Java, etc...)
- Run truClient, which executes JavaScript as a full blown browser.

Comment: Assuming that what you mean by "the HTTP respons stream" is all that comes back from the server in the response to a request. 
Using i.e. Scope=Headers will look only in the HTTP header part of the HTTP respons stream?

Comment: Yes, unscoped is all.   With scope a limited filter is in place